# API provided data in dropdown in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, response

Hello Flutter developers! I am trying to pull data from my API to display in a dropdown. I will actually have 2 different drop downs that require two different api calls. I am currently trying to get the first one to work, which is a list of products. In another place in my program, I am able to successfully receive the list of products. However I am just displaying them, not adding them to a dropdown. In that instance, I am able to use Future Builder, because it is the only call I am making in that part of the program. Here is my current code. When I get to this page, the page itself loads, but my list of products returns as empty when I try to print it to the console.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/models/products_list_model.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/routes/route_helper.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class EditDevicePortWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String deviceId;
  final String portId;
  final String publicId;
  final String label;
  final String portProduct;

  const EditDevicePortWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.deviceId,
      required this.portId,
      required this.publicId,
      required this.label,
      required this.portProduct})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditDevicePortWidget> createState() => _EditDevicePortWidgetState(
      deviceId, portId, publicId, label, portProduct);
}

class _EditDevicePortWidgetState extends State<EditDevicePortWidget> {
  final String deviceId;
  final String portId;
  final String publicId;
  final String label;
  final String portProduct;
  late String _selectedProduct = portProduct;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getProductList();
    super.initState();
    print(allProducts);
  }

  _EditDevicePortWidgetState(
      this.deviceId, this.portId, this.publicId, this.label, this.portProduct);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          publicId + ' - ' + label,
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
            iconSize: 40,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.offNamed(RouteHelper.getPortProfile(
                  deviceId, portId, publicId, label));
            },
          ),
        ],
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.h * 1,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [],
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 10.h,
                thickness: 2.h,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 0, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Product:',
                          style:
                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          alignedDropdown: true,
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: _selectedProduct,
                            iconSize: 30,
                            icon: (null),
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.sp),
                            hint: Text('Select Product'),
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedProduct = newValue!;
                                _getProductList();
                                print(_selectedProduct);
                              });
                            },
                            items: allProducts.map((item) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: new Text(item.productName),
                                value: item.productId.toString(),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<TankProduct> allProducts = [];

  Future<List<TankProduct>> _getProductList() async {
    final allProductsUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.TANK_PRODUCTS_LIST_URI);
    final response = await http.get(allProductsUrl, headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AppConstants.TOKEN,
      'X-API-KEY': AppConstants.API_KEY
    });
    Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    (body["tank_products"]).forEach((product) {
      allProducts.add(TankProduct.fromJson(product));
    });
    return allProducts;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **setState({})** once you set the data in **allProducts** to refresh the UI and reflect the data. You are not doing anything with the returned value, so you can make the return type as **void**

Example:

```html
Future<void> _getProductList() async {
    final allProductsUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.TANK_PRODUCTS_LIST_URI);
    final response = await http.get(allProductsUrl, headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AppConstants.TOKEN,
      'X-API-KEY': AppConstants.API_KEY
    });
    Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    (body["tank_products"]).forEach((product) {
      allProducts.add(TankProduct.fromJson(product));
    });
    setState({});  // reload the UI
  }
```

Comment: two thing though, you eliminated my data model <TankProduct> and secondly, the reason I was returning allProducts was so that the products list was added to my List variable allProducts.  It seems that the way you have set this up, its not taking those things into account.

Comment: In your code, you are just calling ` _getProductList();` in the `initState({})` method. you are not setting the return value to anything.

Comment: in my _getProductList() method I was returning the products after they were added to my List variable, allProducts. As you can see in my original code, then later in my code, where I would be using the list for the dropdown, I can use the . after item and even successfully choose productName. This tells me that I am successfully seeing my data model. I am just unsure why the actual returned data is not shown from the API.